# Dex method count limit in older android versions

Tags: android, dex

I know there is a dex method count limit of 65k. I got an APK that contains 64k methods in its dex and I can install and run it just fine on and Android 4+ device, but not on an Android 2.3 device. Is there a different dex method count limit in older Android versions?

Comment: What is causing you to have 64k methods? If you're using Google Play services and Android Studio, you could take advantage of [granular dependencies](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split) and only include the parts you need.

Comment: On 2.x there is a 5MB dexopt buffer limit. You are probably hitting that and not the "number of methods" limit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878324/running-apps-containing-large-amount-of-code

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks that seems to be it. The dex is actually over 9MB. If you write it again as answer instead of a comment, then I'll mark it as accepted. Grüsse nach Deutschland :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 2.x there is a 5MB dexopt buffer limit. You are probably hitting that and not the "number of methods" limit. See [Running apps containing large amount of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878324/running-apps-containing-large-amount-of-code)